# C - Vsprintf and variable arguments list

Tags: c, list, arguments, concatenation, printf

Now, the aim of the program is to take four names through a variable argument list and concatenate them using vsprintf() into a single string called 'total'.  As the program currently is, only the first name appears in string 'total'.  How can I solve this problem please?  Thanks :)

Comment: `int vsprintf(char *str, const char *format, va_list ap);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signature is `int vsprintf(char *str, const char *format, va_list ap);`.

The second argument is the usual `printf` format string... so:

```
void concat(char *total, ...)
{
   va_list pointer;

   va_start(pointer, total);
   vsprintf(total, "%s %s %s %s", pointer);
   va_end(pointer);
}
```

This of course only works with exactly 4 strings, but you requested to implement this with `vsprintf`, which doesn't work for the generic case.

Note: you're missing `<stdio.h>`, and it's `int main()`.